# Why is the header not working in this code?

Tags: php

The php code to get to the header after executing the queries

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "", "travels");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $fname1 = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname1 = $_POST['lname'];
    $pnum1 = $_POST['pnum'];
    $email1 = $_POST['email'];
    $fcode = $_POST['fcode'];
    $sql = "insert into customer_info(fname,lname,pnumber,email) values ('$fname1','$lname1','$pnum1','$email1')";
    $sql1 = "insert into booking_info(fname,lname,pnumber,email,f_code) values ('$fname1','$lname1','$pnum1','$email1','$fcode')";
    $sql2 = "update flight_info set seats_available=seats_available-1 where flight_code='$fcode'";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
    mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
    header("Location: Booking_confirm.php");
}
?>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form action="Booking.php" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fname">First Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" id="fname"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lname">Last Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" id="lname"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pnum">Phone Number: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="pnum" class="form-control" id="pnum"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email-Address: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="flight">Flight No: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="fcode" class="form-control" id="fcode"/>
                </div>
                <form action="Booking_confirm.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
                    <button type="Submit" name="Submit1" class="btn btn-primary">Book</button>
                </form>
            </form>
        </div>
```

This is how my code looks. for some reason my header is not working and i am not able to find out why.
Help would be appreciated.
I have tried every possible change to get the header to work but of no use

Comment: Welcome. What "header" are we talking about here? What about those two nested forms you have, why two? Fyi, your second form (`action="Booking_confirm.php"`) knows nothing about the form fields you put in your first form (`action="Booking.php"`)

Comment: @kerbhloz the header i am talking about is in the php code i want the three sql queries to be executed and go to Booking_confirm.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two nested forms, your first form `action="Booking.php"` contains all fields while the second, nested form `action="Booking_confirm.php"`, only contains the submit button an `NO` fields.

Replace

```
<form action="Booking_confirm.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
  <button type="Submit" name="Submit1" class="btn btn-primary">Book</button>
</form>
```

with

```
<button type="Submit" name="Submit1" class="btn btn-primary">Book</button>
```

When clicking submit there is no `$_POST['fname']`, `$_POST['lname']` etc.

---

Edit: you also might need to replace

```
<form action="Booking.php" method="POST">
```

with

```
<form action="Booking_confirm.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
```

depending on where your "header"/code is placed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is not white space or html tags or any output, before the header() function...

upload the entire code, structure so we can help you find the solution